# Remove top and right axis in princomp plot

Tags: r, pca, princomp

I have a little problem, I want to remove the top and right axes (I don't know what's the name of that axis, sorry) of my PCA biplot, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Is there a way to remove it?

I read that `bty=1` works to have only the left and bottom axes, but it doesn't work.

```
biplot(PC.LC50, col=2:6, xlab="1st Principal Component (71.2%)", ylab="2nd Principal Component (15.9%)",  xlabs=c("Puerto Colombia", "Soledad", "Barranquilla", "Valledupar", "San Juan", "Sincelejo", "Monteria", "Cienega", "Cartagena"), pch=21, cex=0.75, xlim=c(-0.6,1),bty=1)
#Error en plot.window(...) : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "bty"
```

I tried using it separately:

```
par(bty="1")
#Error en par(bty = "1") : invalid value specified for graphical parameter "bty"
```

I don't know how to use that command, or if it is the one to remove the top and right axes.

Comment: Well what have you tried so far?

Comment: Any reproducible example perhaps?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question, my bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.  It seems `biplot` accepts the `axes` argument.  I cut out some of your original code so it's easy to see what I did.  The `at` in `axis(1, ...)` is the `xlim` value from the original plot

```
biplot(PC.LC50, axes = FALSE)
axis(1, at = c(-0.6,1))
axis(2)
box()
```

Comment: Excelent! it works just perfect! Thank you very much Mr. Richard Scriven. The upper numbers and the right numbers disappeared. Now my plot is just what I needed.

Comment: Glad I could assist. :)